# Watin--Can't address buttons in a nested frame

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, frame, watin

I've been using Watin for a few months.  I've learned a lot but can't seem to figure this one out:

I need to access a button in a frame.  When I look in the IE developer tools (F12) I see a `<frameset name="WRAPPER">` then nested inside of there I see another `<frameset name="MAIN">` then nested inside of there I see the frame that I need to access: `<frame name="leftFrame">`.

When I tried this code:

```
FrameCollection wrapper = ie.Frames;
```

I get this error:

> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the html that developer tool gives you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the

`"htmlDocument.all.tags("iframe")"`

to

`"htmlDocument.all.tags("frame")"`

it seems to solve this issue.

It was [reprted in Watin 2.1 with win7](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3290877&group_id=167632&atid=843727),

Check this related thread:
[Error when accessing the Frames in Watin new version 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882415/error-when-accessing-the-frames-in-watin-new-version-2-1)