# Altering WatiN.Core dll to work with frames AND iframes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, watin

Alright so this may be a total n00b question but I'm using the WatiN 2.1 library with Visual Studio 2013 and I'm trying to automate a mostly javascript-based webpage. I've done this task already using VBA but I wanted to redo it in C#. The webpage has multiple  AND  elements and some necessary fields are contained in lower levels of each. In VBA, I was able to navigate the page by simple doing something like this:

```
ie.Document.frames("frameID1").Document.frames("frameID2").Document.getElementByID("target").Click
```

This line of code would work whether frameID1 or frameID2 were frames or iframes. It didn't seem to matter to VBA. I tried a similar approach in C# using WatiN but it seems like the Frame feature in WatiN only recognizes  as frame elements and simply recognizes a  element as a simple HTML element.

That being said, I have read the question regarding this found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882415/error-when-accessing-the-frames-in-watin-new-version-2-1)
 but this is where my questoin arises. They say the solution is to alter the code for the AllFramesProcessor method and that fixes it. But how exactly do you access and modify this code? This code is contained in a .dll which I've tried to modify using .NET Reflector. I've export the source code, opened it in Visual Studio, found the code to modify and did so, but when I tried to build a new release, it threw multiple errors. Any suggestions on how to modify this block of code properly and get a version of WatiN that can handle  elements?

Comment: No need to decompile it, the sources are available for you at http://sourceforge.net/p/watin/code/HEAD/tree/

Comment: So `ie.Frame("frameID1")` won't give you the first level frame? What about: `ie.Frame("frameID1").Frame("frameID2").Element("target").Click()`